# Why does my image size increase by 4 times when upload to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, base64, png

I am currently uploading an image to my s3 bucket using POST presigned url. My image has extension of png and has a size of 5.6Mb. When upload to s3 bucket the image is stored as base64 encoded string. The size of the image changes from 5.6MB to 23.3Mb on s3. Is there is an explanation for that. I know that the image size becomes 1.37 times the original size when encoded.

Comment: Do you have versioning enabled on the bucket? Maybe sum of all versions adds up to 23MB?

Comment: nope it is disabled

Comment: ok. so how the encoding is done? You do it on your localhost yourself, and then upload the encoded file to s3?

Comment: yes that what happens

Comment: Then I don't. So on your localhost the size is 7.67MB but on S3 it is 23.3MB? And you upload it directly, using s3 CLI or s3 console?

Comment: nope I upload it using s3 api using presigned urls from my localhost

Comment: Could you post the exact CLI code of how you upload it?

Comment: I am not using a cli I Am using aws sdk api where  i request a presigned url then i upload it directly from the client

Comment: 2 years later.. I'm having this issue. Did you found a solution for this? @Ahmed

Comment: When i saved it in another format jpeg or png everything was fine